# How to change all the related icons in chrome-extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am writing a chrome-extension which opens a popup page on click. 
Through my `manifest.json` I specified the icon to be displayed in chrome and it works very well:

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "mocker-icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Click here!"
},
```

The popup is open through the `chrome.windows.create` api:

```
chrome.windows.create(DEFAULT_WINDOW_OPTIONS, onMainWindowCreated);
```

But I would like to change two more icons:

1) The one displayed in the task bar associated to the popup:

[image]

2) The one displayed in the chrome-extension page when installing/installed it:

[image]

I tried to google it since few time but it seems all the answers refer to the icon on chrome, the one I already set up through the manifest correctly.

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set the icon for the browser action (the `default_icon` in fact, since the [icon for a browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#icon) can change dynamically), not the icon for the extension itself.

This is `icon` in the manifest:

```
"icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
           "48": "icon48.png",
          "128": "icon128.png" },
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/icons

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot man, upvoted it and waiting ten minutes in order to accept it (cannot accept it immediately)